Why did the Supreme Court have original jurisdiction in United States v. Shipp
United States v. Shipp, 20 U.S. 563 (1906) was the only case in history in which the Supreme Court conducted a criminal trial (as opposed to reviewing a matter of law arising in a criminal case that started in a lower court). This occurred because the DOJ filed its complaint directly in the Supreme Court, i.e., as an original jurisdiction case.
However, Shipp and his co-defendants were not ambassadors, so how could this case have been within the Supreme Court's original jurisdiction? Is there an unwritten principle that states that contempt of a particular court is always within that court's original jurisdiction (in addition to anything else that is explicitly codified as being within its original jurisdiction)?

It was within the jurisdiction of the Supreme Court because it was a trial for contempt of an order of the Supreme Court (issued in connection with a normal appeal).  From the syllabus of the opinion:

After an appeal has been allowed by one of the Justices of this Court, and an order entered that all proceedings against appellant be stayed and his custody retained pending appeal, the acts of persons having knowledge of such order in creating a mob and taking appellant from his place of confinement and hanging him constitute contempt of this Court, and it is immaterial whether appellant's custodian be regarded as a mere state officer or as bailee of the United States under the order.

